# Maximize area spanned by convex hull of a permutation

Tags: permutations, convex-geometry, discrete-optimization, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

Given an ordered set $X = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n), x_i \in \Bbb R^2$ and a permutation $P$ defined on $X$ and that shuffles the order of the elements in $X$,

$$P(X) := (p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n)$$

and we can get the prefix sum set $S$ of $P(X)$

$$S = \left( p_1, p_1+p_2, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \right)$$

And we can get a convex hull of $CH(S)$, and I'm interested in maximizing the area of $CH(S)$.

Since given $X$, $\text{area}(CH(S)) = f(P)$ is a function of $P$. And there exists $n!$ different $P$, how can one find the optimal permutation as efficient as possible?

Comment: I would be surprised if this could actually be formulated as minimizing a convex function subject to convex constraints. As a general theme, if we introduce permutations, the problem becomes much more challenging (combinatorial optimization usually requires more computation than convex optimization). You may want to look for a convex relaxation of the problem (sort-of like how to how approximate solutions of the combinatorial Max Cut problem are found using a convex relaxation)

Comment: Yeah, so my interest is mostly in the extreme points of convexhull of a set of permutations, and more or less, the convex hull of convex hulls generated by all permutations is just a zonotope. But I’m not sure whether zonotope indeed has the maximum area